Diffrent size of rendered HTML DOM elements on 4K and FHD screen
I'm working on a project and I've encountered a problem in Chrome. I have no idea why, but the inner height of rendered DOM element is slightly smaller on 4K screen than on the standard 1920x1080. Simple test, html page containing only
<h3>Test</h3>

This h3 element on 4k display:

After dragging Chrome window to FHD monitor:

0.7px inner height difference. After adding CSS styles to ensure same size:
line-height: 1.2;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;

Difference in height is 0.005px. 4K:

FHD:

I aware it's not much but this project involves generating PDF files using Chromium engine and after many lines there is few pixels difference. I want to ensure same result in browser and in output file, regardless window size. Changing Chrome window size doesn't affect rendered heights.
Does anyone have ideas on what might be causing this and how to fix it?

AFAIK you will have similar problems between different browsers not just screens as pixels are a theoretic size depending on viewers perspective thus a small screen is higher density than a desktop. THE CSS concept is all screens are seen at the angle subtended by 96 dpi at arms length and we all have different lengths of arm! the problem is a pixel cannot be divided but CSS says there can be 100s of dots per pixel.

The closest to a standard is say that a PDF is 1056 pixels high as that's a given (unless your outside USA where it is 1,122.5) both are incorrectly applied in many systems so Acrobat in a browser will not be the same as acrobat in a desktop but both should state 816 is statement size.

it is a shame there is no universal measure as just checking some sites say that PDF nominal 72 point inches should measure as 71.9090909 !!!!!!!!!
